# Would it be possible to genetically engineer a human immune to weapons? If so, up to what point?

Tags: internal-consistency, genetic-engineering

I'd like to know exactly how much we could genetically engineer a human to be able to withstand any serious hit by a blunt object, a knife or sword slash, or a gun shot. Doing this with things like extremely hardened skin or bones, extremely fast regeneration abilities and things that would be possible with genetic engineering is my goal.

My guess is that it may be possible to make him almost immune to blunt objects and slashes, but I am seriously doubtful about gun shots, and things like missiles or atomic bombs would be totally out of place.

For the answer I am considering anything valid in theory, even if it has not been possible to implement it yet IRL.

Basically, what I am asking is: How would it be possible to generate a completely biological human reasonably resistant to conventional, chemical and biological weapons?

Comment: I guess it depends on how much you are willing to change the human.

Comment: You might be interested in some of the already existing questions on the site, such as [Could a creature evolve a biological “bulletproof vest”?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/33364/28789) or [Are Engineered 'Super-Soldiers' a Realistic Possibility?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/56245/28789)

Comment: As defenses improve, so will weapons - changing size, shape, quantity, and usage to match the newer need.

Comment: anything that you make human made of will still be suffocable. So just burn them. You either burn them or remove oxygen from their lungs long enough they will die.

Comment: weapons range from spitting a watermelon seed to blasting a Tsar bomb... I hop you realize they cannot call for the same resistance.

Comment: I think if you want to make a human immune to anything, you might seriously hinder his abilities to "operate normally" (walk, grab objects,...). Plus, your human will always have a weakness considering the amount of factors you would have to take into account (blunt force, piercing projectiles, diseases, thermal resistance, electromagnetic waves,...)

Answer (score 3):

Knowing [The shield and spear paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irresistible_force_paradox), I can say that whenever you create the most resistant being, it can also be destroyed. How would you destroy a person made of diamond? Well, with diamond of course.

As a global civilization, we faced this in the war-smith arts through history. With nuclear weapons being around the last century, humankind has reached the point of destroying itself in the attempt to kill others.

Nevertheless, the best approach I can think about is backuping the human itself, so if it gets desintegrated, it can be restored. We could then make some type of cell akin to a [T lymphocyte cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_T_cell) that memorizes all the cells, then regenerate all the body with [Omnipotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_potency#Totipotency) [stem cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stem_cell). In short, it is conceivable.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Wikipedia (Honey badger):

> Because of the toughness and looseness of their skin, honey badgers are very difficult to kill with dogs. Their skin is hard to penetrate, and its looseness allows them to twist and turn on their attackers when held. The only safe grip on a honey badger is on the back of the neck. The skin is also tough enough to resist several machete blows. The only sure way of killing them quickly is through a blow to the skull with a club or a shot to the head with a gun, as their skin is almost impervious to arrows and spears

I think this is the most resistant we could get.

Also thicker, denser skull would be a good defense, but I don't think we would look like "human" with all those things